# Dynamic CGPath with 2 arcs and 2 lines

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgpath

[image]

The blue dot and the blue area will need to be able to collide and to do so I need to calculate a path to create the physics body from.

I need help figuring out how I would create the path for the darker blue ring area (the darker portion of the ring within the light blue highlight).

I know it would have two arcs and two lines, but I need to be able to calculate the path based on the distance from the center and the angle (so in the image for example the angle would be 45 degrees, or PI/4, radius 1 would be 180px and radius 2 (the smaller one) would be 165px.

How would I create a dynamic path like this?

Comment: spritekit or cocos2d-iphone? You can only be using one or the other. If you want to be sure to get an answer for the engine you are using you should remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: removed cocos2d-iphone